# Aligned glosses in orgmode (for export to odt/doc)

Tags: emacs, org-mode, linguistics, odt

I'm contemplating writing linguistics articles in orgmode in cases where I know I will need to provide a doc(x) file (normally I would otherwise use LaTeX).

One of things I will need to be able to is produce numbered examples with aligned interlinear glosses (like these: http://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php ). It's been a while since I've done this in a doc(x)-ish format, but the obvious ways would be (1) to do something with tab alignment or (2) use borderless/invisible tables.

Can anyone suggest how this (or some other solution to producing interlinear glosses) might be implemented in an orgmode->odt/doc/docx setup?

Edit: one potential solution would be an orgmode setup which produces borderless tables with an "optimal width" column setting. I don't know how/if to do this in orgmode though.